# Removing key from json file in Python (getting TypeError)

Tags: python, json

I have a this json file:

```
{
 "DailyForecasts": [
  {
   "Temperature": {
    "Minimum": {
     "Value": 2.9
    },
    "Maximum": {
     "Value": 16.1
    }
  },
 "HoursOfSun": 12,
 "AirAndPollen": [
    {
      "Name": "AirQuality",
      "Value": 37,
      "CategoryValue": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "UVIndex",
      "Value": 5,
      "CategoryValue": 2
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to remove "CategoryValue" key from "AirAndPollen" array. I tried this Python code, but getting:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

My Python code:

```
import json

with open('accu-test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for remove in data['DailyForecasts']:
    del remove['AirAndPollen']['CategoryValue']

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

What's the recommended approach in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AirAndPollen is a list, you would have to iterate through it too.

```
for i in data['DailyForecasts']:
    for j in i['AirAndPollen']:
        del j['CategoryValue']

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)

 # {'DailyForecasts': [{'AirAndPollen': [{'Name': 'AirQuality', 'Value': 37},
 #                                       {'Name': 'UVIndex', 'Value': 5}],
 #                      'HoursOfSun': 12,
 #                      'Temperature': {'Maximum': {'Value': 16.1},
 #                                      'Minimum': {'Value': 2.9}}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a statement `print(remove['AirAndPollen'])` you'll see that `remove['AirAndPollen']` is not a single object but rather a *list*.  You need an additional loop to operate on each on of those objects in turn.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
data = {
    "DailyForecasts": [
        {
            "Temperature": {
                "Minimum": {
                    "Value": 2.9
                },
                "Maximum": {
                    "Value": 16.1
                }
            },
            "HoursOfSun": 12,
            "AirAndPollen": [
                {
                    "Name": "AirQuality",
                    "Value": 37,
                    "CategoryValue": 1
                },
                {
                    "Name": "UVIndex",
                    "Value": 5,
                    "CategoryValue": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

air_and_pollen = data.get("DailyForecasts")[0]["AirAndPollen"]
for i in air_and_pollen:
    i.pop("CategoryValue")
data.get("DailyForecasts")[0]["AirAndPollen"] = air_and_pollen
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nested_delete` from the [nested_lookup](https://github.com/russellballestrini/nested-lookup) module:

NB: I wrapped the json data into a *content* variable:

```
from nested_lookup import nested_delete

#specify the key u wish to remove
content = nested_delete(content,'CategoryValue')

print(content)

{'DailyForecasts': [{'Temperature': {'Minimum': {'Value': 2.9},
    'Maximum': {'Value': 16.1}},
   'HoursOfSun': 12,
   'AirAndPollen': [{'Name': 'AirQuality', 'Value': 37},
    {'Name': 'UVIndex', 'Value': 5}]}]}
```